# Using Cookie to Pre-populate PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, cookies

Using information that a user has already provided in their registration (and which is now in an SQL database), when the user signs in and then clicks to go to a form, I want some of the form to already be pre-populated. The log-in form is as such:

```
<?php 
session_start();
// check for required fields from the form
if ((!isset($_POST['email'])) || (!isset($_POST['password']))) {
header("Location: userlogin.html");
exit;
}
//connect to server and select database
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database")
        or die(mysqli_error());
 // use mysqli_real_escape_string to clean the input

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['password']);

// Create and issue the query
$sql = "SELECT username FROM frmak_form_1 WHERE 
    email = '".$email."' AND 
    password = '".$password."'";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

//get the number of rows in the result set; should be 1 if a match. 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1 ) {
// if authorized, get value of username
while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username = stripslashes($info['username']);
}




 $_SESSION['user']= $info['username'];
 $_SESSION['login_until'] = time() + 60 * 60; // login expires in 1 hour

 $display_block = "<p>Welcome, ".$username."!</p>
 <br /> <br />
 <a href='submitReview.php'>Click Here to Submit a Review!</a>";
 }
 else {
header("Location: userlogin.html");
exit;
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Login REDIRECT!!!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php echo $display_block; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Then the "submitReview.php" file is:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $s = &$_SESSION;    // Login status is ON and has NOT yet expired

 $isLoggedIn = isset($s['login_until']) && $s['login_until'] > time();
 if($isLoggedIn):
 $username = $s['user'];

 $s['login_until'] = time() + 60 * 60;    // extend login expiration to an hour from now. 

  else
  unset($s['login_until'], $['user']);
  $username = null;

  endif;



  exit; 
  }
  ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>
 <label>username</label>
 <br />
 <input name="usrnm" id="usrnm" type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/>
 <br />

 </p> 
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

In the example above, I'm only trying to display the user name in the form, because that's the only part that I want pre-populated as just a text field. The others are a radio button and a check box field, and I know those will take an even more complicated argument, so I'm just trying to make the simplest one work first.

If what I've done is not even remotely what should be done, could someone please just direct me toward a good tutorial for such things? I'm trying to teach myself PHP and MySQL, so sometimes it is a bit overwhelming. Thanks!

Comment: In case where you missed it, you did not redact the name of your website on the first code block.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the advice in the answer below... still not working. I am pretty sure I have some syntax errors, with {} ; ()  :  etc... As I said, I am trying to learn this all by myself, so please bear with me...

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd file, `$username` doesn't mean anything, so nothing will be pre-populated. Also, You should not take a cookie at face-value to decide whether the user is logged in. Anyone can create a cookie `auth=1` and send it to your PHP server.

The simplest approach to learn is to instead rely on [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

At the top of every script, (or in a file that is included at the top of every script), do:

```
session_start();
```

This will tell PHP to set the SESSION cookie if this is a new user, or to read the existing SESSION cookie and retrieve the matching, previously saved session information.

Once the user provides his login credentials, save the status in session:

```
$_SESSION['user']= $info['username'];
$_SESSION['login_until'] = time() + 60 * 60; // login expires in 1hr
```

Now to check whether the user is logged in from any script, all you do is:

```
session_start();
$s = &$_SESSION; // $s is now an alias of $_SESSION
// Login status is ON and has not yet expired
$isLoggedIn = isset($s['login_until']) &&  $s['login_until'] > time();

if($isLoggedIn):
  $username = $s['user'];

  // extend the login expiration to an hour from now
  $s['login_until'] = time() + 60 * 60;
else:
  // user is unknown or login has expired
  unset($s['login_until'], $['user']);
  $username = null;
endif;
```

If you include this block (untested code) above all your pages, then you can always count on:

- `$username` being accurate, or `NULL` for an unknown user,
- `isLoggedIn` telling you whether this is a logged in user.

You can store other things in $_SESSION as well and reuse them on other pages. Just remember to check for login status before you do anything that requires authentication.

Also important to understand that sessions rely on cookies, so if a user clears his browser cookies, even if he logged in 2 minutes before, the PHP server will not recognize her and `start_session()` will create a fresh new session for her.

Before you jump in and use sessions, [read this page](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

PS: This is not related to your question, but **never** store plain text passwords in your DB. Use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to store and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check.

Comment: @LaraO'Regan ok. I tried to help you. If you found my answer helpful, either select or upvote or both.  Good luck.

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect your advice, still not working. I know I probably have some syntax errors, as I said, I am trying to teach this to myself, so I ask that you bear with me!!! Your help is appreciated.